# Searching for files with specific file content

Tags: windows, search

I am trying to edit lot of files which has specific file content. I need to search for those files which have some content.

Is there any software which can do this type of search with huge accuracy.

I have tried searching using Windows 7 but looks like it misses many files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The Windows native search can be quite limited ...

I'd suggest you look at the [File Content Finder](https://geosystemsdev.com/products/file-content-finder/) app on the [Windows app store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/p/file-content-finder/9mzc4sk6j6bp) (disclaimer - I'm its developer). It's specifically designed for searching file contents without indexing. It supports all major file formats - pdf, doc(x), xls(x), pptx, and others. It can even search scanned documents.

Its filtering lets you optimise and refine your search by multiple criteria - file type, creation/modification dates, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FIND "string" pathname` or `FINDSTR "string" pathname(s)`from the windows command line. See [this](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html) guide.

Comment: I have a complete folder structure and have many files with different formats.
I need to search for files which contains say "6.7.2" in the file.
The idea you have provided is to search a file for some contents?

Comment: No, you need to read the guide, it has examples on `FINDSTR`. You can do something like `FINDSTR /s /i 6.7.2 *.*` which will search for "6.7.2" in all files below the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

I face this issue on a daily basis, and I've come up with two solutions:

1. Text editors, supporting the "find in file" feature (Notepad++ being a simple, free example).
2. Ubuntu app (from Canonical Group): UNIX/Linux supports finding in files, using the command `find . -exec grep ...`.

As far as Windows search is concerned, its quality has reduced that heavily the latest versions that I've decided not to use it anymore.